# JSP servlet JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, servlet-3.0, setattribute

When I send attribute 'saved' from servlet to jsp, if it equals to true I show alert msg otherwise I want to assign it to false in the second refresh.

Servlet:

```
 saved = true;
 request.setAttribute("saved", saved);
 response.sendRedirect("temp/pr_home.jsp");
```

JSP:

```
<c:choose>

        <c:when test="${saved==true}">

                <c:out value="${saved}"> </c:out>
            <div class="alert-box success" role="alert" >
                    Project Review has been saved! <a href="pr_home.jsp" > click here to see details  </a>
            </div>
            <br />

        </c:when>    

        <c:otherwise>
            <div class="alert-box failure" role="alert">
                    This is a danger alert—check it out!
            </div>
        </c:otherwise>

    </c:choose>
```

View:
[image]

The flag variable 'saved' still in true all the time !! So, also alert message appears each time I refresh the page :(

Sorry for my English.

thank you for your help.

Comment: In your servlet code you are assigning `saved=true` manually , that's why same block printing all the time.

Comment: Yes but I want to assign it to "true"just one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you redirect to .jsp . 
Because **.sendRedirect(String path)** method doesn't transfer the request and response objects.
You typically use this technique when you want to transfer control to a URL outside of your application.
So I suggest this method to call a jsp page:

```
getServletContext.getRequestDispatcher("temp/pr_home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And for the **.setAttribute(String name, Object o)** method is better use a wrapper class, for example:

```
request.setAttribute("saved", new Boolean(saved));
```